# Can't Access cowin api through pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, amazon-cloudfront, pythonanywhere

I have the following code to be run on pythonanywhere inside a flask application

```
import requests

headers = {                                                                                                                                               
    'Host': 'cdn-api.co-vin.in',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=360311&date=15-05-2021"

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data={})
```

It gives me the following error on deployment.

```
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We cant connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the
 app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentati
on.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: T8CDbBTWmri-1gJ4CIEASotEbtHQjGflb-rCmBASEt1ojwC3R9FN_Q==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

This works properly on the localhost but on deploying gives the above error. Please suggest if there is any way of reverse proxy or some other way to deploy.

Comment: there are many 403 closed issues on cowin github. Kindly check them

Comment: did you resolve this issue? i've tried using multiple headers, but while they work in local execution, I'm getting a 403 in pythonanywhere.

Comment: @ProgramSpree I have only found out that you have to hit the cowin api from Indian servers and web hosting platforms like pythonanywhere or heroku don't have indian servers. The workaround is to host it on either AWS EC2 instance or Google cloud platform where you can select Indian region.

Answer (score 2):

You can check closed issues on [Cowin Open Tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin/issues)

Issue number #183  [`Public API returning 403`](https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin/issues/183)

https://github.com/cowinapi/developer.cowin/issues/183

For further questions, please visit Open Tracker on GitHub. You can even raise a new issue if your query is not resolved based on closed issues.

Answer (score 0):

*IP outside India is blocked* by the Cowin server and if you deploy using Heroku then its default region is **US** So, try using AWS and select **Asia Pacific (Mumbai)** region.

Hope this will work